# Imported files do not appear inside Docker container

Tags: php, docker

I touched Docker for the first time yesterday, and I don't know much about web server administration in general. Just a heads up.

I'm struggling to make a simple PHP "hello world" run inside a Docker container. I have built a Docker container with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM nanoserver/iis

MAINTAINER nanoserver.es@gmail.com

ADD http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.31-Win32-VC11-x64.zip php.zip
ADD https://nanoserver.es/nanofiles/vcruntime140.dll C:\\Windows\\System32\\vcruntime140.dll
ADD https://nanoserver.es/nanofiles/iisfcgi.dll C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\iisfcgi.dll
ADD https://nanoserver.es/nanofiles/info.dll C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\info.php
COPY hello.php C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\hello.php

ENV PHP C:\\php

RUN powershell -command Expand-Archive -Path c:\php.zip -DestinationPath C:\php

RUN setx PATH /M %PATH%;C:\php 

ADD https://nanoserver.es/nanofiles/php.ini C:\\php\\php.ini

RUN powershell -command \

    rm C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\Applicationhost.config ; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -uri https://nanoserver.es/nanofiles/Applicationhost.txt -outfile C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\config\\Applicationhost.config ; \
    Remove-Item c:\php.zip -Force
# The above request fails, but I don't see how it would be relevant to my question.

CMD ["powershell.exe"]
```

I would expect this Dockerfile to create a container with c:\inetpub\wwwroot\info.php, c:\inetpub\wwwroot\hello.php and c:\php. However, Powershell inside the container gives me this output:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> ls


        Directory: C:\inetpub\wwwroot


    Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
    ----                -------------         ------ ----
    -a----        4/11/2017  11:55 AM            703 iisstart.htm
    -a----        4/11/2017  11:55 AM          99710 iisstart.png
```

It feels like there is some fundamental that I haven't grasped. Could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

On windows you have to use forward slashes in paths in the `Dockerfile`.

Official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile

**From docs**

On Windows, the destination format must use forward slashes. For example, these are valid COPY instructions.

```
COPY test1.txt /temp/
COPY test1.txt c:/temp/
```

However, the following will **NOT** work.

```
COPY test1.txt c:\temp\
```

If either source or destination include whitespace, enclose the path in square brackets and double quotes.

```
COPY ["<source>", "<destination>"]
```

Also note that copying to non-existing paths in the image normally do not trigger an error. The directory must exist.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I modified my Dockerfile to the following: https://pastebin.com/raw/SA956z9y
Still, none of the expected PHP-files appear inside the container.

Considering that my first Dockerfile was executed without errors, was my syntax autocorrected for me?

Comment: try `COPY ["hello.php", "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/"]`? .. it should do the same though. Maybe also build without cache: `docker build --no-cache .`

Comment: @Magnus Is there a possibility that `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/` doesn't exit when you copy the file? Worst case you can make the directory before copying.

Comment: This does work. But for some funny reason it won't happen when the container is built.

Comment: Looking at the dockerfile, I don't see any reason why the directory would not exist when the files are copied. I guess you know this better than me.